# Variance of a continuous and discrete

Tags: probability, expectation

I am trying to solve the following.

> $X$ is an exponential random variable with mean $\theta$ while $Y$ is a Bernoulli random variable with probability of success $p$.  Find the $Var[XY]$

I have no idea what to do here, because one is continuous while the other is discrete.  All I know is that I am trying to add all the $xy P[X=x,Y=y]$ but how do we work on this case?

Comment: Wasn't this asked (with no personal input) very recently? By yourself, perhaps?

Comment: Hint: Compute E(XY). If you try in earnest, you will see you forgot to copy a hypothesis about the joint distribution of (X,Y).

Answer (score 0):

The probability distribution of variable $z = XY$ is
$$
f(z) = (1-p)\delta(z) + p \theta e^{-\theta z} \Theta(z)
$$
where $\delta(z)$ is the usual Heaviside delta function and $\Theta (z)$ is a step function keeping the exponential only for positive $z$.

The expectation is 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} z (1-p)\delta(z) dz + \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} z p \theta e^{-\theta z} \Theta(z)dz = (1-p)\cdot 0 + p  \theta \int_{0}^{+\infty} z e^{-\theta z} dz = p/\theta
$$
The second moment about zero is 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} z^2 (1-p)\delta(z) dz + \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} z^2 p \theta e^{-\theta z} \Theta(z)dz = (1-p)\cdot 0 + p  \theta \int_{0}^{+\infty} z^2 e^{-\theta z} dz = 2p/\theta^2
$$
The variance is thus
$$
\sigma^2 = \left( 2p/\theta^2 \right) - \left( p/\theta \right)^2 = \frac{p(2-p)}{\theta^2}
$$

Comment: Hi Mark - Your defn of the Exponential pdf is inconsistent with the OP's specification that $E[X] = \theta$ ... just inverse parameterisation at play.

Comment: This makes things look more complicated than they are. **Assuming independence**, $E(XY)=E(Y)E(X)=pE(X)$ and $E(X^2Y^2)=E(Y^2)E(X^2)=pE(X^2)$ and the proof is over.

Answer (score 0):

> $X$ is an exponential random variable with mean $\theta$ while $Y$ is a Bernoulli random variable with probability of success $p$.  Find the $Var[XY]$

Given:

- $X \sim Exponential(\theta)$ with $E[X] = \theta$ and $Var(X) = \theta^2$.
- $Y \sim Bernoulli(p)$ with $E[Y] = p$ and $Var(Y) = p(1-p)$.

*Solution:* The easy way to solve this is to express the variance of a product $(X*Y)$ in terms of: the moments of $X$ (which we know) and the moments of $Y$ (which we know). In particular, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent:

$$Var(X Y) = Var(X) Var(Y) + Var(X) E[Y]^2 + Var(Y) E[X]^2  = p(2-p) \theta^2 $$

Comment: This makes things look more complicated than they are. Assuming independence, $E(XY)=E(Y)E(X)=pE(X)$ and $E(X^2Y^2)=E(Y^2)E(X^2)=pE(X^2)$ and the proof is over.

Comment: Yes - that is neater.